# ColdFusion 11 webservice not working with https, works with http

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, wsdl, iis-8, coldfusion-11

I'm getting a `HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error` when I try to access in the browser a webservice .cfc over https. It works fine over http. No problem for .cfm pages.

The same webservice works fine with https on a ColdFusion 9 install.

How can I get this fixed for ColdFusion 11? It seems to be something between IIS  and ColdFusion.  What should I try?

This works:

```
http://my.server.com/webservice.cfc?wsdl
```

This does not:

```
https://my.server.com/webservice.cfc?wsdl
```

returns error:

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

The web server is IIS 8, ColdFusion 11

```
Detailed Error Information:
Module     IsapiModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    ISAPI-dll
Error Code     0x00000000
Requested URL      https://my.server.com:443/jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll
Physical Path      D:\ColdFusion11\config\wsconfig\1\isapi_redirect.dll
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
```

---

> (2018-06-30) - Update with solution

After reading (https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4203045) and (http://www.shavedmonkeys.com/index.cfm/coldfusion-blog/deploy-ssl-https-webservice-in-coldfusion/)

**Reason for error**:
CF 10, 11 and 2016 do not pre-configure support of https for axis2 web services.

**Solution**:
Modify CF's axis2.xml file to add an https transportreceiver line (the default location for this is 
`{drive letter}:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF`)

change this line:

```
<transportReceiver name="http" class="coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFAxisServletListener"/>
```

to this:

```
<transportReceiver name="http" class="coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFAxisServletListener">
  <parameter name="port">80</parameter>
</transportReceiver>


<transportReceiver name="https" class="coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFAxisServletListener">
  <parameter name="port">443</parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be a couple things...

ColdFusion 9 only had Axis 1 web services.  CF11 uses Axis 2 by default.  You can either set it to use Axis 1 in the CF Administrator, in your `Application.cfc`, or when you create the web service object you can set it to use Axis 1 instead of 2.  This might solve the problem.

`createObject(
  "webservice", 
  "https://my.server.com/webservice.cfc?wsdl",
  {wsversion="1"}
)`

The other thing it might be, is the certificate.  Sometimes you need to manually add a certificate to the Java certificate store otherwise CF will be unable to connect over SSL.  There are my articles about this with a little bit of searching, but they all boil down to this, basically: http://www.bryansgeekspeak.com/2014/12/coldfusion-11-java-keytool-import-cert.html

Comment: I changed to Axis 1 in both code and CF Admin and now it works, thank you. Can you explain why Axis 2 does not work?

Comment: Apache Axis 2 was a complete rewrite and is not compatible so if the web service you're consuming requires an Axis 1 client, it will not work with the Axis 2 client.

Comment: I'm trying to understand who is in this case the Axis 1 client, is it IIS that is the client not capable of https if ColdFusion is set with Axis 2? If that is the case, is there anything I can do to make it compatible with Axis 2?

Comment: CF is the client.  So when you do createObject() you are creating the client.  The webservice itself is what determines if it supports axis 2 or not.  So unless you are also the author of the webservice then no.  If you are then yes you can write it in such a way that it supports Axis 2.